# QWebSocket "Unknown Error"

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, qt5

I've been trying to set up a websocket client using the Qt websocket class.
Unfortunately I haven't been able to progress past the first step: connecting my client to a server.

I'm certain that the connection is possible because both the Go [ws websocket client](https://github.com/yhat/ws) and the C++ [easywsclient library](https://github.com/dhbaird/easywsclient) can connect and interface with the server.

The relevant part of my code is the following:

```
  QWebSocket socket;
  socket.open(QUrl("ws://localhost:9999"));
  qDebug() << socket.error() << socket.errorString();
```

When running the program, I get the following (unhelpful) message:

```
QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError "Unknown error"
```

Is there any way to clarify the error and/or fix the problem?

P.S. While the easywsclient library can connect and interface with the server it only does a marginal job, which is why I'd rather use the Qt class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error. The `open()` is asynchronous. Connect the `connected()`, `disconnected()`, `error()`, `textMessageReceived()` signals to the slots of your `QObject`-derived object. Or use some lambdas if it's a very basic application:

```
QWebSocket socket;
QObject::connect(&socket, &QWebSocket::connected, [] { qDebug() << "connected"; });
QObject::connect(&socket, &QWebSocket::error, [](QAbstractSocket::SocketError error) { qDebug() << error; });
socket.open(QUrl("ws://localhost:9999"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize open() was async. I've tried your code with lambda slots as well as actual proper slots, but my client is still unable to connect to the server. Debugging with Wireshark, I see that after the initial handshake the client immediately sends a FIN,ACK and terminates the connection. Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Update: miraculously the websockets have begun to work. It seems that a port change did the trick. This was a local issue affecting only me. Thank you very much for all of your help :)